# VisualStudio / Resharper : getting rid of tooltips in the editor

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

[image: Annoying tooltip]

How can I get rid of these super annoying tooltips that somehow always seem to cover what I type?
It comes from ReSharper and I can't see any way to hide that annoyance.

Does someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unticking ReSharper | Options | Environment | IntelliSense | Parameter Info | "Automatically show parameter info" checkbox.

Comment: Oh, I found there is also a delay in ms.. I can probably get the best of both worlds! thanks!